# $scope isn't changed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am writing a scheduling service, so there are plenty of times in each week; when you click on each time its Unix format will send to a modal and the user can book it, now I wanted to pass Unix time to a ngDialog module by writing the following code.

## ScreenShots

[image: Booking Service]A view of booking service

[image: when you click on 9:00 button the modal(ngDialog) will be opened]when you click on 9:00 button the modal(ngDialog) will be opened

[image: Unix time]I wanna Unix time in input above.

## Controller

```
schedule.controller('schedule', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', function($scope, $http, ngDialog) {
$http.get('/zt-api/business/admin/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]).success(function(data) {
        $scope.admin_times = data;
        $scope.duration = {
            startTime: "",
            endTime: ""
        };
        $scope.clickToOpen = function(start) {
            ngDialog.openConfirm({
                template: '/static/partials/staff_admin/ngdialog/admin_block_time.html',
                scope: $scope
            }).then(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            }, function(reject) {
                console.log(reject);
            });
            $scope.duration.startTime = start;
            console.log($scope.duration)
        };
    }
});
});
}]);
```

## HTML

```
<div class="morning"  ng-hide="hideMorning" ng-repeat="(key4, array4) in array3.times | filter: {'part': 'morning'}">
    <div class="daytime" ng-click="clickToOpen(array4.unix)" id="{[{ array4.unix }]}" ng-show="array4.part=='morning'">{[{ array4.timestamp.split(" ")[1].slice(0,5) }]}</div>
</div>

**array4.unix returns Unix time.**
```

I want to when I run clickToOpen function it be able to change `$scope.duration.startTime` to `start`, but, it just changes for less than a second! How can I amend it?

Comment: Okay...I'm missing the point. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want just to change the value of  $scope.duration.startTime to array4.unix of each element, just this, but it doesn't change forever, it just changes for about 500ms!

Comment: Not sure why you are initializing startTime with a string, but then assigning it a numeric value. Your question and code is a bit confusing; could you clarify with some contextual info or a practical example?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a controller to ngDialog.openConfirm() and log $scope like this.

```
ngDialog.openConfirm({
            template: 'templateId',
            controller: function($scope){
              console.log($scope);
            },
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }, function(reject) {
            console.log(reject);
        });

}
```

You will notice any values that are passed in though the parent controller are accessible through $scopes.$parent object as seen in the image below. Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5WSQ7oHxWSCOjDu6BAcB?p=preview) that works passing $scope to ngDialog and showing the main controllers $scope.dateTime in a input box inside ngDialog

[image: $scopes parent]